# Installation issue- Emmet, PyV8-Linux 64 bit, Sublime Text 2

Tags: 12.04, plugins, sublime-text

I recently began learning to code, and have run into some challenging installation issues. I recently installed Emmet in Sublime Text 2 running in Ubuntu 12.04. Emmet installed just fine, however after "manually" installing the PyV8-Linux 64 bit binary, by copying and pasting the two files from the zip folder into a folder I created in ST2's packages folder, Emmet still isn't working. And, in ST's console I'm getting an error message. For those of you who are familiar with this, your help is appreciated! The full error message from the console is listed below. Thanks.

```
...

Reloading plugin /home/dqcrevive/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Emmet/emmet-plugin.py
PyV8: Creating new thread
Emmet: Creating thread
Emmet: Loading https://api.github.com/repos/emmetio/pyv8-binaries/contents
Reloading plugin /home/dqcrevive/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/HTML/encode_html_entities.py
Reloading plugin /home/dqcrevive/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/HTML/html_completions.py
Reloading plugin /home/dqcrevive/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Package Control/Package Control.py
Reloading plugin /home/dqcrevive/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/PyV8/PyV8.py
plugin init time: 0.793147
loading bindings
loading pointer bindings
found 1 files for base name Default.sublime-theme
theme loaded
app ready
pre session restore time: 0.962301
using gamma: 1 (err: 0)
startup cache, total files: 103 cache hits: 103
startup time: 1.10101 (package setup was not run)
loaded 837 snippets
Emmet: Loading PyV8 binary from https://raw.github.com/emmetio/pyv8-binaries/master/pyv8-linux64.zip
Exception in thread Thread-104:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
  File ".\threading.py", line 736, in run
  File "./emmet/pyv8loader.py", line 271, in run
    return self.trigger('error', exit_code=self.thread.exit_code, progress=self)
  File "./emmet/pyv8loader.py", line 290, in trigger
    c(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_error() got an unexpected keyword argument 'progress'

Package Control: No updated packages
```

Answer (score 2):

Some Google searching turns up a bit of troubleshooting on Github for this very problem. Specifically, this specific remedy: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/issues/465

**In a nutshell:**

Manually install PyV8 and restart Sublime.

**The details:**

1. [Download PyV8 here](https://github.com/emmetio/pyv8-binaries) for your operating system.
2. Create a folder called PyV8.
3. Place the contents of the downloaded `zip` folder into the PyV8 folder (created in the step above).
4. Go into sublime text, type `ctrl shift p` and type `browse packages` -> enter
5. Move the PyV8 folder (from steps 2 and 3) into the folder that opens (the Sublime package directory, launched from Sublime in step 4).

These instructions should work for Sublime 2. In case folks are looking, the link above has instructions for Sublime 3.

Hope this works!

Comment: your solution work fine for Sublime Text3 too. thks.